# How to find posts without comments in last 90 days in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have to find all the posts without comments in last 90 days and actually I could't find a way to resolve this query

First of all, here are the tables:

```
CREATE TABLE POSTS
( 
  POST_ID NUMBER(10) NOT NULL,
  TITLE VARCHAR2(100) NOT NULL,
  CONTENT VARCHAR2(2000) NOT NULL,
  DATE_CREATED DATE NOT NULL,
  USER_ID NUMBER(10) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT POSTS_PK PRIMARY KEY (POST_ID),
  CONSTRAINT USER_POST_FK
    FOREIGN KEY (USER_ID )
    REFERENCES USERS(USER_ID )
);

CREATE TABLE COMMENTS
( 
  COMMENT_ID NUMBER(15) NOT NULL,
  POST_ID NUMBER(10) NOT NULL,
  DESCRIPTION VARCHAR2(500) NOT NULL,
  COMMENT_DATE DATE NOT NULL,
  USER_ID NUMBER(10) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT COMMENTS_PK PRIMARY KEY (COMMENT_ID),
  CONSTRAINT POST_COMMENT_FK
    FOREIGN KEY (POST_ID)
    REFERENCES POSTS(POST_ID),
  CONSTRAINT USER_COMMENT_FK
    FOREIGN KEY (USER_ID )
    REFERENCES USERS(USER_ID )
);
```

Basically I have to find all the posts with comments where the most recent comment are 90 days or old.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have to find all the posts without comments in last 90 days

This suggests `not exists`:

```
select p.*
from posts p
where not exists (select 1
                  from comments c
                  where c.post_id = p.post_id and
                        c.comment_date >= sysdate - interval '90' day
                 );
```

Note:  You probably want `trunc(sysdate)` to remove the time component.

Comment: Thanks! I had to do a little change in the last line, using "TO_DATE(c.comment_date, 'dd/mm/yyyy') >= TO_DATE(SYSDATE, 'dd/mm/yyyy') - 90" works fine for me.

Comment: In your data model, `comment_date` is a `date`.  There should be no reason to convert it.  The same is true of `sysdate`.

Comment: @MikeJensens `TO_DATE(SYSDATE, 'dd/mm/yyyy')` is a really bad idea, but it will have the side effect of truncating the date. If truncating it is what you need, then use `trunc(sysdate)`.

Comment: Exactly, I was wrong. Writing directly "c.comment_date >= sysdate - 90" worked very well.

Answer (score 0):

```
select post_id      --    or:    select *
from   posts
where  post_id not in (
                        select post_id
                        from   comments
                        where  comment_date >= trunc(sysdate) - 90
                      )
;
```